# low priority http upload in .net

Tags: c#, .net, http

I'm writing a program that uploads huge amounts of data and I need to limit it's interference with web browsing and other user activities.

The upload is composed of many large-ish files that are transferred individually, the connection must be a standard HTTP POST (I have no control of the server) and I need to control the HTTP headers (the server uses them for authentication and metadata)

It's important that the upload will resume full speed when the user is no longer using the internet because otherwise it will never finish (I expect it will need to run for a week or more at full speed to complete).

I want to solve this problem by somehow making my HTTP connection low priority, detecting open browser windows and slowing down does not solve the problem because (a) the user may be using a non-browser app (FTP, twitter client, e-mail, etc.) and (b) I don't want to slow down if there's an open idle web browser window.

I've found BITS but I think it's not relevant for me since I need it to be a standard HTTP POST.

I'm using .net 3.5, the program is written in C# and I'm currently using HttpWebRequest for the upload.

**Clarification:** I’m writing consumer software that will run on the customer’s personal computer at home. My beta testers complain that the internet is slow when they run my program (understandable, since I am using all their bandwidth) so I want to give higher priority to other programs so their internet is no longer slow.

There is no fancy network infrastructure that can prioritize packets on the network and no IT team to install and configure anything, I do expect most customers will have a cheap wireless router they got for free from their ISP

Comment: how do you expect to detect other application activities from the user so to slow down if user has browser open and active and to speed up if your application is alone?

Comment: @Davide Piras - I think that is the question @Nir is trying to ask.

Comment: @Davide @iamdudley - actually I don't want to detect if the browser is open - I want to tell Windows to process my http (or tcp) connection only after it finishes processing connections from processes that interacts with the user (or all other processes, since there's probably no way to tell if a process "interacts with the user")

Comment: Would it be possible for you to set the task manager to have a lower prio on your app? Something like > start App.exe /BELOWNORMAL

Comment: @Nir BITS has been designed for this for the download, did you check already if it can work also for upload? What you need is a QoS aware upload scheduler.

Comment: @Davide - do you have any idea where I can find "a QoS aware upload scheduler"? or how I can interact with it if it's already on the machine?

Comment: @Marthin - the process priority controls CPU not network - but I'll try it and see if it helps, thanks

Comment: This is usually solved in the network infrastructure (traffic shaping, QoS routing)

Comment: @sehe - do you have any idea how to communicate with this network infrasructure?

Comment: @Nir: That is like asking "Where can I find the road", instead of asking directions. It is hard not to. However, I assume you mean: how can I dynamically 'program'/'configure' the router's priority tables; You (usually) can't. But it shouldn't be difficult to get your network admin to configure it so uploads get a maximum bandwidth % allotted (perhaps only when not idle, on a specific port or timewindow). It all depends on the feature set of the router. It may be worth investing in one that has [QoS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service) and traffic shaping if it doesn't support it

Comment: @sehe - I'm writing consumer software that people will run from home. I expect to see mostly cheap routers people got for free from thier ISP and there is no network admin I can call.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question.

Comment: @Marthin - CPU priority (unfortunately) doesn't affect network performance at all.

Comment: What I would try is to think whether you really need to transfer all that data. If you do, try to compress it as much as possible, maybe even using custom compression algorithm tailored specifically for the data you're transferring. Of course, this would either require the control of the server or the creation of some proxy server.

Comment: @svick - thanks for the comment - but the program is used for off-site backups (so I have to transfer all the data), the data is already compressed using am algorithm tailored for the data - but its a bit old and there are slightly better algorithms today (so while it's possible to compress it more the gains wouldn't be that big), I don't have control of the server and adding a proxy is not financially possible (bandwidth costs money, tens of GB of bandwidth per customer costs lots of money)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simultaneously keep track of number of bytes your app sends and the total bytes sent on the network using the [System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPv4InterfaceStatistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics.aspx) class' bytesSent Property at a given interval.  Subtract the total bytes your app has sent in that interval from the total bytes sent on the network (during the same interval).  If the difference is high enough to where you need to throttle your uploading then do so.  Once the difference becomes small enough, crank up the uploading.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you have the throttling end of the problem covered, so you only need to know two things:

- WHEN to reduce upload speed

and

- HOW MUCH to reduce it

Now, using other API-s is maybe fine, but why learn them and introduce all new kind of bug generators, when you can do something more simple.

Now - the problem with uploads with most internet connections (say ADSL) is that they consume precious UPLOAD that is extremely limited, say 256-512k.  User probably report the problems because your upload is killing the requests they send, so they can't get any data back.

I am proposing that you do two things...  to resolve WHEN problem, do this:

- create simple GET request for your web server
- measure time that is needed for the server to fully process and respond, by reading the response to the end
- use one cut-off value for 'busy' and 'free' connection, or measure times for each client and calculate their cut-off value
- if time is greater, you are busy, do throttling, else, go full speed
- you can repeat this as much as you can - for example every minute

To resolve HOW MUCH is another question.  First, you should measure how much you can upload when nobody else is using the connection - your baseline upload speed per client.  Then, using the WHEN technique, you can throttle down the upload until you get 'free' result that will work for their connection.

Hope I made myself clear - ask if anything needs clarification.

EDIT:

Few more thing to consider:

1. sending binary data through the POST is wasteful since everything is encoded in BASE64.  You should inspect some other means of upload.
2. throttling against the web server could be problem because if you upload big chunk of data slowly, maybe server will timeout
3. if you combine 1+2, you could devise a plan that can splice the data into chunks, say 1KB or more, and send them one by one.  It alone could solve your throttling problem, if you do it in serialized fashion.

Comment: there is a major problem with your "WHEN" algorithm - you can't have cutoff values - the connection can be slow because it's busy, because it's on the other side of the world passing 3 under sea lines and a satellite link before it get's to me or because the customer has a crappy ISP (and slowing down even more because the connection is already slow is not smart). At the same time if the connection is fast it doesn't mean the user isn't screaming in rage because GMail is slow.

Comment: and about your things to consider 1. I don't send the data in web form format, I send the raw unencoded binary stream 2. yes it is a problem 3. I have no control of the server and I can't make it accept chunks, also with 1KB chunks I expect the TCP/IP+HTTP overhead to become significant, I think the optimal chunk size is in the low MB range

Comment: well, sometimes you'll have to settle with some kind of compromise, because you want your problem optimized by several dimensions which are too far stretched.  you can have cutoff values, but you just have to determine WHAT they are - it will be individual from PC to PC, connection to connection, so measure, log, calculate, experiment. well, if there is a better way, I'll be glad to know.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider taking a more passive approach to the problem.  You simply need to set the packets your application generate to a lower priority than the other packets origination from the system.  Then let the network take care of scheduling the packets.

It has been my experience that even low end consumer network devices (Personal firewalls, gateways, cable modems, DSL modems, even the Windows OS's, etc.) support traffic shaping.  Use this capability and set the traffic you generate to a low priority and all other packets will default to a medium priority if their priority is not explicitly set.  The medium packets will be allotted the bulk of the available bandwidth when they exist and your triffic will be squeezed out.  When the medium priority packets do not exist on the network your packets will be allowed to use the available bandwidth.

Comment: This is what I wanted to do in the first place - do you know what API I can use to do it? preferably without having to write my own HTTP stack

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't tried any of this myself, I can only provide pointers.

For detecting network activity, you can try using [NMAPI](http://blogs.technet.com/b/netmon/archive/2008/10/29/intro-to-the-network-monitor-api.aspx) or [Packet Monitor](http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/pmon/)

[WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/misc/links.htm) also has a ported .Net library but not sure if it captures http traffic.

Other than these, there are no QoS libraries in .Net AFAIK.

If you're willing to delve into C++, [QoS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can help.

None of this is straighforward and looking at your comments, I'm not sure if this is feasible within your timeline, but it is what it is. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, detecting network activity may actually be a workable solution. The QoS API seems even more promising but it looks like it's only about reserving bandwidth for yourself (and even then, most of it doesn't work on Vista and later), it you can point me at the QoS function that makes you a low priority stream (inside your computer or your local network only, I want to let the user keep using the internet not to give the ISP permission to drop my packets) this will be the accepted answer.

Comment: I believe you need to specify that in `FLOWSPEC` structure (`SendingFlowspec`). This msdn article may help - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301862.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Thinking outside the box :

What about just scanning for human activity : keyboard and mouse action, or presence of screensaver, or locked screen ?
Then when no user is in front of the computer, you upload full speed, otherwise, upload at a minimum rate.

Comment: I thought about it, but this suffers from 3 problems, 1. doing keyboard/mouse detection right is surprisingly difficult. 2. no human at the keyboard does not mean there isn't important network activity (the user might have started a download and left, for example) 3. slowing down when someone id editing a local word document is not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how to implemnt it in .NET but couldnt you perhaps do like smaller test with round-trip-time (RTT) to the server and if you like the result you get back you increase the package load. If you have "congestion" on you client then you should perhaps have a little longer RTT and then lower the load?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have no idea how to do what you suggested and I'm not even sure how RTT works, I don't have time in the project schedule to learn the inner workings of TCP/IP so I can't try it for the first version - but, unless I get a simpler answer, I will try it for version 2 and I'll post the results here (but it will take a while)

Comment: It's not very much to learn it just as you say TCP/IP at work. You basically send a small package and see how long time it takes to return. However, you might get fooled by the RTT since there might actually be congestion some where on your net even though your client isn't active at all.

Comment: I would probably run this in its own thread, that then throttles the true put for your main app.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a solution where you get the maximum upload speed for the machine and 'poll' every 5 seconds if you're application is not uploading if there is any network traffic.

This should make sure you don't eat all network traffic but have the maximum speed most of the time.

Comment: And don't forget to add some form of compression!

Comment: I don't understand, you say I should stop uploading every 5 seconds and listen to the network to see if there is other traffic? this seems to me like it would have big performance penalty for my program (if I wait 1 sec every 5 I get to spend 16% of my time waiting – that more than a full extra day for a week long upload) and it will completely break down if the other program is constantly using little bandwidth, like an AJAX e-mail client checking for mail (so instead of sharing the network I now spend all my time waiting)

Comment: And the data is already compressed (I wish I could re-compress it with a better algorithm but the server doesn’t support this)

Comment: Every five seconds seem like a safe bet. You could use some form of 'mouse' movement detection or 'keyboard' press detection to see if someone is present and you should start polling.
Furthermore you can see how much traffic is being generated and simply fill the rest of the bandwidth with your own upload.

Comment: How do you detect the user’s total bandwidth? How do you detect other program’s bandwidth usage? How do you detect and adapt to a web page sending a small ajax request every 10 seconds? I’m sorry, but your strategy takes a hard problem (how to do low priority upload) and replace it with lots and lots of other hard problems - just think about detecting the user’s internet bandwidth for example (the only way to do this is to measure it, but that’s only reliable if there’s no other network traffic – and if this is the case we don’t have a problem to begin with).

Comment: If you can write some proof-of-concept code that demonstrate this can actually work I’ll happily apologize but it seems to me going this way will be more work that the entire app – and it’s a fragile solution even without adding more problematic functionality (keyboard/mouse detection is surprisingly hard to do right).

Answer (score 0):

Is providing a bittorrent-like maximum bandwidth cap out of the question? You could adjust the cap based on the time of day (full speed in the middle of the night, 50% during peak hours, for example), or give the user the option to configure their maximum speed and scheduling options.

Comment: This is a consumer home product so: 1. home peak hours are not standard and connection speed vary wildly so I'm unlikely to be able to provide good defaults 2. do you really expect a non-techie user to even understand let alone configure this?

Comment: Both good questions.  No I wouldn't expect the average non-techie user to be able to effectively configure this, but you could do some research on your user base to determine average peak hours.  In order to avoid giving the user too much control (which could cause confusion), you could give them a few different "schemes" to choose from.  Perhaps a late night heavy bandwidth scheme, or a school/work hours scheme that uses full bandwitdh during the day.  Just an idea.